# My JavaScript code gives error when i try to compile

Tags: javascript

When trying to create a password-protected button on my site the error: '(' expected. is given and all other questions on here have proven useless (I am a beginner to javascript so please forgive me if the answer is obvious)

```js
function passWord2
var askaccess = 1();
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Password To Access Page', ' ');
while (askaccess < 3) {
  if (!pass1)
    history.go(-1);
  if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "gimmethedeets") {
    alert('Password Correct');
    window.open('logslist.html');
    break;
  }
  askaccess += 1;
  var pass1 =
    prompt('Password Incorrect.', 'Password');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & askaccess == 3)
  history.go(-1);
return " ";
```

Comment: A function declaration requires `( )` for the formal parameter list, even when the list is empty. It also requires `{` and `}` around the function body.

Comment: Do you realize that you send the password in clear text on the page? It is just one keystroke away for anyone to see what the password is, and even the page you are going to if the password was correct.

Comment: If the answer I provided is not sufficient please edit your question with more details. and/or add comments on it as to why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are <strike>probably</strike> more issues here but a function has a `function functionname(variablename){}` signature.

**None of this is a secure password entry and can be easily seen/guessed by a user.**

```js
function passWord2() {
  var askaccess = 1();
  var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Password To Access Page', ' ');
  while (askaccess < 3) {
    if (!pass1)
      history.go(-1);
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "gimmethedeets") {
      alert('Password Correct');
      window.open('logslist.html');
      break;
    }
    askaccess += 1;
    var pass1 =
      prompt('Password Incorrect.', 'Password');
  }
  if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & askaccess == 3)
    history.go(-1);
  return " ";
}

// call it
passWord2();
```

Rewrite with some guesswork on intent.  Comments where appropriate

```js
function checkForPassword() {
  // declare stuff, use let to keep block scope,
  // these have values here to not get reference error
  // not strickly needed but a good habit, 
  // when it gets a value read:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let
  let entryAttempts = 1,
    entryValue = "",
    correctValue = "gimmethedeets";
  // this gives 2 attempts due to the 1 initial value and not 0
  while (entryAttempts < 3) {
    entryValue = prompt('Please Enter Password To Access Page', '');
    // check for null empty values 
    if (entryValue != null && entryValue.length > 0 && entryValue.trim() != "") {
      // I find this slightly more clear but same as  history.go(-1);
      window.history.back();
    }
    // value null if they hit cancel, protect from that
    if (entryValue != null && entryValue.toLowerCase() == correctValue) {
      alert('Password Correct');
      // open the new window, different than making THIS page go there as ino window.location ='logslist.html';
      window.open('logslist.html');
      break;
    }
    entryValue = prompt('Password Incorrect.', 'Password');
    entryAttempts += 1; // last in while loop
  }
  // slight restructure to make intent clear, fix bitwise & to to logical &&
  // a guess on the intent here
  if ((entryValue == null || entryValue.toLowerCase() != "password") && entryAttempts === 3) {
    history.back();
  } else {
    // to be clear if entry is "Password" it returns after 2 attempts
    return " ";
  }
}

// call it
let entry = checkForPassword();
```

Comment: Still need to remove the `()` behind the `1` at the first line of the `passWord2` function.

Comment: unless that IS a function which we do not know, as I said, there are other problems outside the scope of the question

Comment: The digit `1` is not a valid JavaScript identifier, so it can't be a function.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Tried that, simply caused more problems than it solved

Comment: let me rewrite this fully to show the difference as I think I can guess what you are trying to do here.